# Get JSON data for clicked on ID only

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of JSON data. The base of it has 2 ID's and within each ID there is further attachment data. I am trying to click on one base ID and display it's attachment data on the second page. How can I only get the info for the clicked on ID?

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "deliveryMessageList": [
            {
                "id": "73c624c9-6db7-4fd2-ac91-c1084aee0565",
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "id": "fb1e6d31-4c4e-4356-be5a-827ea5ec422d",
                        "attachToDeliveryMessage": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "160edceb-cda7-483c-a2b9-786f583b523d",
                        "attachToDeliveryMessage": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "bfd600ad-754f-444d-bddb-f5cf4d7727b8",
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "id": "e4454f8c-4ecb-444e-a82a-318bbcee1c11",
                        "attachToDeliveryMessage": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "791a73eb-59cc-4bba-8b16-d442169a7923",
                        "attachToDeliveryMessage": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My UI looks like this

[image: example]

I have tried to add an ID to the click event like this but am unsure what to try next

```
  getCustomerAccountDocs(selectedItem: any, index: number) {
    this.CustomerAccountDocsService.getCustomerAccountDocs()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.customerAccountDocs = data;
    });
  }
```

HTML code

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of customerAccountDocs; let i=index" (click)="getCustomerAccountDocs(item, i)">
    <td> {{item.accountNumber}}</td>  
    <td> {{item.id}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post it.

Comment: edited in question

Comment: Do you only need help in getting that particular object/index? Or do you want to pass that data to the second page as well

Comment: Just getting the object please. I will use a shared service to pass the data.

Comment: But you do have the `selectedItem` in your click-handler. Why can't you then access `selectedItem.attachments`?

Comment: @Anton because "attachments" is a sibling, not a child

Comment: What is in `this.customerAccountDocs`? I assume everything inside the `deliveryMessageList` list?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: I don't see it. `selectedItem` should have two properties - the `id` and the `attachments`. Of course there are "siblings" - as they are both properties of the same object (`selectedItem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like its pretty much a question of how to get all other siblings of a particular JSON node. I don't know HOW you're accessing the ID exactlly (through a loop or what..) but I'll simply show you how to access it in a loop. Let's assume that your main JSON object quoted above was stored in a variable called "main" then work from there:

```
var embedded = main["_embedded"]["deliveryMessageList"] //or however u access the JSON keys..
var newJSON = {};
embedded.forEach(x => { 
    for(var k in x) {
        var currentIDsiblings = {};
        var ID = null;
        for(var subkey in x[k]) {
            if(subkey != "id") {

                currentIDsiblings[subkey] = (x[k][subkey]);
            } else {
                ID = subkey;
            }

        }
        newJSON[ID] = currentIDsiblings;
    }
});

/* now you can access newJSON[myID], to get all of its siblings */
```